# Sensor data stores previous values,even though cache is cleared

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I developed simmple count steps app,which shows on TextView current footsteps,it works also on OnPause mathod,and on and on..

The problem is,I want to erase previous data and start counting steps from the beginning,I cleared data in phone's settings but it did not help. The app loaded from Android Studio even once again shows 0 as the first value and then shows 300 and more as i am using it. Somehow the sensores still have all the data.

Can you help?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
private final int PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY = 0;
private TextView Steps;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor mCountStep;
// private boolean x;
int CountSteps;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
    }
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    Steps = findViewById(R.id.textKroki);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {

        mCountStep = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        //  x= true;
    } else {

       Steps.setText("NO SENSOR."); //x=false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor == mCountStep) {
        CountSteps = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
        Steps.setText(String.valueOf(CountSteps));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, mCountStep, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) != null) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mCountStep);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   // deleteCacheData();
    super.onDestroy();

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sensor you are using is TYPE_STEP_COUNTER. According to developer.android.com that is the intended result. The sensor shows the steps taken by the user since last reboot while the sensor was activated.

What I think you are looking for is TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion